# Why Can't I update My Database Using Azure Mobile app

Tags: .net, azure, ef-code-first, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-api

I'm literally new to Azure , I need some guides :"(

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you can see , I have successfully published my .Net backend
to the service , and I do a little bit code first inside it ,

I'm so confused where to check the changes (new tables created by code first)
on Azure after publish successfully ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like Fiddler or (my favorite) Postman to check out your tables; or write a mobile client.

Check my book out - http://aka.ms/zumobook - it will guide you through the process.  Alternatively, there are a set of quickstart tutorials on the Azure Mobile Apps documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/; or you can read the "30 Days of Azure Mobile" blog series at https://shellmonger.com/